# Extracting movie release date from developers' API for research purposes

Tags: api, release, imdb, netflix, movies

I want to extact movies' release date on DVD's for my research purpose. Also it would be helpful, if i can extract different release dates of the same movie in different countries. I can see this information on Wikipedia and IMDB , but I would like to know if i can extract this information programmatically through some API. Its my personal project and we don't aim to build any revenue or service. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might try the open Movie database:
http://omdbapi.com/

Assuming they haven't stepped on anyone's toes legally (Movie information is controlled quite tightly) this should do the trick for you, I think.